# If algorithm in Latex

Tags: conditionals, algorithms, algorithmic, ifthenelse

I want to create a simple algorithm in my latex document. I have a variable which comes to my latex template from the web-form it can have just two values "yes" or "no", so in case if this value "yes" I want in my document appears text "option1", in case if this value "no", I want in my document appears text "option2". As far as I understood I should use \usepackage{algorithmic}, but I don't know the syntax of this package, here is what I tried (but it doesn't work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \IF{  {{based}} ="yes" }
    \STATE option1
  \ELSE
    \STATE option2
  \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From your question it is not (yet) fully clear what you want. The `algorithm` and `algorithmicx` packages are intended to typeset (display) pseudo-code in your document, they do not actually execute code. There are other packages and (La)TeX internals that provide functionality for conditionally changing the displayed content in a document, such as the `ifthen` package. However, it is not clear where your variable comes from, what kind of web form you are talking about, how the LaTeX source is generated (or if it is typed manually), what the compile sequence is - please clarify.

Comment: @Marijn yeah, {algorithmic} is definetly not what I need here,  ifthen package is a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `algorithmic` is for typesetting algorithms in your document, not for programming. You want to use `\usepackage{ifthen}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\based}{yes}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\based}{yes}}{option1}{option2}
\end{document}
```